# Magento - How can I filter display same name product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I import the +8000 product on Magento 1.9.1 through Import data flow,
and all products created as simple product and most of them are repeated by the same name but the attribute of size is different and I create the connection between them via upsell product.

For example  product "BITZ POULTICE BOOT"  have 2 different size from  size attribute  views and with upsell option I selected all  of them for each one and now in catolog displaye 2 item from "BITZ POULTICE BOOT" with same name.
how can I filter catalog display as the name just display one of same name product, mean from product "BITZ POULTICE BOOT" just show one of them not all.

by the way, from the first I did not have the option to use bundle product or group because there was 8000 item need to import our database .

Is there any chance to filter the same name product and display just one of them ( no matter which one)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am following you correctly, but Magento would normally handle this with Configurable products by setting the simple products to "Not Visible Individually" so that only the Configurable product is shown in a category list.

Comment: Yes its true but the problem is we already import with many difficulties in sharing host 8000 products and we already upload their picture one by one and now we have 8000 products as Simple product not Configurable or Grouped one, so is there any way to filter same name product with coding in catolog views?

Comment: I am terribly confused. You want only one of these products to show on the category list, but there are no configurable products? How is a customer ever supposed to find any product other than the one you show?